# May I purchase a TurtleBot with an arm similar to Bilibot?

Tags: robotic-arm, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd be willing to pay more for a purchase option that would let me buy the TurtleBot FULL package that additionally includes "AN ARM SIMILAR TO THE BILIBOT" with the specs below:

*Custom Designed Acrylic, with aluminum support, providing the perfect balance between strength and low weight.
*Geared Motors
*Lifts objects from the ground up to 17 Inches in the Air
*Lifts objects weighing up to 3 Lbs

Am I able to buy such a TurtleBot package? (I sure sure hope so!!)
Please let me know how much this would cost.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10283/may-i-purchase-a-turtlebot-with-an-arm-similar-to-bilibot?/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-06-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-16**:
I'm working on getting an arm on the TurtleBot ...be patient...and many other people are working on cool add-ons too. So if you want a TurtleBot get one and join the community!

**Comment by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on 2011-06-16**:
Because I prefer the expandable physical shelf design of the Turtlebot. The great Turtlebot community support seems far more active at the moment too.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-16**:
If you want an arm like the one the Bilibot has, why not just buy a Bilibot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are currently creating a metric version of the turtlebot (on [turtlebot.eu](http://turtlebot.eu/)) with options to buy the plates in MDF or in Acrylic. Our site is not complete yet, but on of the first extensions we'll post is a gripper + arm design for the turtlebot.
Other extensions include: dynamixel mount for tilting laser scanner and tilting kinect and an mini-ITX alternative to the current laptop.
I'm finishing the designs and we still need to calculate the costs.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1